# $T$ and $U$ self-adjoint on $V$, $T$ is positive definite. Prove $TU$ & $UT$ are diagonalizable linear operators that have only real eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, self-adjoint-operators

This is a problem from Freidberg linear algebra (4th edition) chapter 6.4.21

The whole problem and the hints are

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space, and let $T$ and $U$ be
> self-adjoint operators on $V$ such that $T$ is positive definite. Prove that
> both $TU$ and $UT$ are diagonalizable linear operators that have only real
> eigenvalues.
> Hint: Show that $UT$ is self-adjoint with respect to the inner
> product $<x, y>' = <T(x), y>$ To show that $TU$ is self-adjoint, repeat the
> argument with the inverse of $T$ in place of $T$.

I have tried

$<TU(x), y> = <U(x), T^*(y)> = <U(x), T(y)> = < x, U^*T(y) > = <x, UT(y)>$

But this didn't work.

I don't know why the hint is given, and I think there is another way of not using that hint.

Because I think "Show that $UT$ is self-adjoint with respect to the inner product $<x,y>'=<T(x),y>$" is a bit contrived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We think of $T$ and $U$ as two matrices.

Because $T$ is positive-definite, $T$=$P^{*}P$. Thus $TU=P^{*}PU$=$P^{*}PUP^{*}\left( P^* \right) ^{-1}$ is similar to $PUP^{*}$. Because $U$ is self-adjiont, $TU$ has real eigenvalues and can be diagonalizable.

$UT=UP^{*}P=P^{-1}PUP^{*}P$ is the same case.

Comment: So the condition " $T$ is positive-definite" is critical right?
In general, if $T$ and $U$ are self-adjoint, $TU$ is not self-adjoint?

Comment: $T$ and $U$ is self-adjoint, then $TU$ is self-adjoint iff $TU=UT$.

Comment: I can see some connections. Thanks